# Is there an elegant way to perform code once in the lifetime of an object in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, c, cocoa

Occasionally I want to perform code once in the lifetime of an object. In the past I've set up a `BOOL` property that I can check for, but that's a little awkward. Is there something built-into Objective-C that elegantly accomplishes this? Somewhat like `dispatch_once`, but tied to the object rather than the lifetime of the application.

Comment: perform code ? not getting, can you elaborate?

Comment: Sorry -- poor phrasing. "Execute a block" is what I really mean.

Comment: The BOOL approach seems perfectly valid and straight forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a dispatch_once_t instance variable to do this. Just beware subtle threading issues (not specific to dispatch_once) if you're going to be using this object on multiple threads. You need a memory barrier at the end of init to be sure that the initialization of the ivar has completed before the object is visible to multiple threads.

Comment: Using `dispatch_once` with an instance variable sounds like a good idea. What are the possible threading issues? Sorry if this is a dumb question, but how can the object be visible to other threads before the `alloc+init` method has returned?

Comment: Memory ordering issues are incredibly unintuitive. If you're concerned about it, ridiculous fish wrote a great blog post on the subject: http://ridiculousfish.com/blog/posts/barrier.html

Comment: Thank you for the link, that is definitely worth reading. - I don't think that is a problem here, because `+[NSObject alloc]` already sets the memory for all instance variable to 0, including the `dispatch_once_t` predicate. - But never mind, I was just curious, and this is not my question! Again, thank you for the link.

Comment: Realistically, on x86, it's very unlikely to be an issue :) Just pointing it out for completeness, and in case you ever end up on something very weakly ordered like an Alpha

Comment: @zlajo, although you're correct about what Apple's docs say, they are overzealous in arguing against using dynamic storage for `dispatch_once()` predicates. This was discussed in depth (with some interesting digressions) on the Cocoa-Dev mailing list [here](http://lists.apple.com/archives/cocoa-dev/2012/Nov/msg00240.html) and continued [here](http://lists.apple.com/archives/cocoa-dev/2012/Dec/msg00138.html). `dispatch_once()` is unsafe on an ivar only in cases where **any** operation on the instance would also be unsafe.

Comment: I've commented on the other approach explaining why it's likely not safe.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/dispatch_once) `dispatch_once` should not be used in that case!

> The predicate must point to a variable stored in global or static scope. **The result of using a predicate with automatic or dynamic storage is undefined.**

An alternative approach would be to use [atomic operations](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/System/Reference/OSAtomic_header_reference/Reference/reference.html). That way it can also be ensured that code is only executed once during the lifetime of an object.

```
@implementation MyClass {
    // int32_t initialized;
    BOOL initialized;
}

- (void)myMethod {
    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        // if (OSAtomicTestAndSetBarrier(1, &initialized) == NO) {
        if (!initialized) {
           // do stuff once

           initialized = YES;
        }
    });
};

@end
```

EDIT: `initialized` has been of type BOOL, which has been corrected thanks to the comments of  Chris Devereux and Stephen Canon.

EDIT: As Catfish_Man pointed out using atomic operations likely leads to problems. Because of that you would have to wrap the whole stuff with a dispatch_sync or something like that, which then makes using atomic operations pointless.

Comment: I'm not an expert on this stuff, but shouldn't it be OSAtomicTestAndSetBarrier here due to the memory ordering issues mentioned in @Catfish_Man's comment? (also, should be an int32_t, not a BOOL flag)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification and sorry for missing that one!

Comment: See my comment on the accepted answer. `dispatch_once()` is safe to use on an instance variable, despite Apple's documentation saying it's not.

Comment: This is actually not safe for a lot of common code patterns. With dispatch_once(), the second through Nth threads to enter the block will wait until the first thread completes. With this pattern, they'll continue on, blissfully unaware that the one-time initialization has not yet finished. If the one-time initialization sets anything, you'll also need a read barrier after the if() on some but not all processors. Atomic operations are difficult and unintuitive to use correctly.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! I still have mixed feelings about using `dispatch_once`. Although I totally understand your explanations and I don't see how the described behavior will change any time soon it feels like using private apis...

Comment: I actually tend to agree. I think the right answer is probably locks (or equivalents), as unappealing as that is.

Comment: (The really right answer is for apple to either update the dispatch_once docs or provide an alternative for this purpose)

Comment: I could not agree more! :-)